# Cannot instantiate the type Deque

Tags: java

```
    import java.awt.HeadlessException;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    import javax.xml.soap.Node;

    public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private int size;
    private Node<Item> head;
    private Node<Item> tail;

    private static class Node<Item> {
        private Item key;
        private Node<Item> leftNode;
        private Node<Item> rightNode;

        Node(Item key, Node<Item> left, Node<Item> right) {
            this.key = key;
            this.leftNode = left;
            this.rightNode = right;
        }

    }


    public Deque() {
        head = new Node<Item>(null,null,null);
        tail = new Node<Item>(null,head,null);
        head.rightNode = tail;
        size = 0;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head.rightNode == tail;
     }
    public int size() {
       return size;
    }
    public void addFirst(Item item) {

       if (item == null) throw new NullPointerException(" trying to add nothing");

       else {
           Node<Item> oldFirstNode = head.rightNode;
           head.rightNode = new Node<Item>(item,head,oldFirstNode);
           oldFirstNode.leftNode = head.rightNode;
           size++;

       }
     }
    public void addLast(Item item)  {

       if (item == null) throw new NullPointerException(" trying to add nothing");

       else {
           Node<Item> oldLastNode = tail.leftNode;
           tail.leftNode = new Node<Item>(item,oldLastNode,tail);
           oldLastNode.rightNode = tail.leftNode;
           size++;

       }
   }

     public Item removeFirst()  {              // remove and return the item from the front

       if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException(" Deque is alrady empty");

       else {
           Node<Item> delete = head.rightNode;
           Node<Item> newFirstNode = head.rightNode.rightNode;
           newFirstNode.leftNode = head;
           head.rightNode = newFirstNode;
           delete.leftNode = null;
           delete.rightNode = null;
           Item myKeyItem = delete.key;
           delete = null;
           size--;
           return myKeyItem;
       }

   }
   public Item removeLast() {                 // remove and return the item from the end

       if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException(" Deque is alrady empty");

       else {
           Node<Item> delete = tail.leftNode;
           Node<Item> newLastNode = tail.leftNode.leftNode;
           newLastNode.rightNode = tail;
           tail.leftNode = newLastNode;
           delete.leftNode = null;
           delete.rightNode = null;
           Item myKeyItem = delete.key;
           delete = null;
           size--;
           return myKeyItem;
       }
   }


   public Iterator<Item> iterator() {         // return an iterator over items in order from front to end
       return new DequeIterator();
   }

   private class DequeIterator implements Iterator<Item> {

       private Node<Item> current = head.rightNode;

       public boolean hasNext() {return current != tail;}

       public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet");  }

       public Item next() {
           if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException("no next");
           Item key = current.key;
           current = current.rightNode;
           return key;

       }
   }
     public static void main(String[] args) { 

   Deque<Integer>[] s = new Deque[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   s[i] =new Deque<Integer>(); // initial each object
   }
   s[0].addFirst(1);
  // s[1].addFirst(2);
   StdOut.print(s[0]);
   //StdOut.print(s[1]);

  } 


   }
```

In the following code I have a compiling error stats that "Cannot instantiate the type Deque".

```
package Assign3;

 import java.util.Deque;



 public class graph {

//private Deque<Integer>[] graphRepDeques;
final static int Amount = 200;

private Deque<Integer>[] s = new Deque[Amount];

public graph(String filename) {

    In in = new In(filename);
    //final int Amount = 200;
    s = new Deque[Amount];

    for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++) {

        String[] currentLine = in.readLine().split("\\s");
        int size = currentLine.length;
         s[i] =new Deque<Integer>(); // why Cannot instantiate the type Deque<Integer>???????
        for (int j = 1; j < size; j++) {
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[j]);
            s[i].add(temp);
        }
    }


}

private  void show() {

    for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++) {
           for (int a: s[i]) {
               //StdOut.print(a + " ");
           }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    graph a = new graph("kargerMinCut.txt"); //whatever text you like with integers
    a.show();
}
```

}

The error I got is

```
Cannot instantiate the type Deque<Integer>
```

I can instantiate Deque in the main function in class "Deque", but why I cannot do it in class "graph"? Very confused here

I appreciate any help thanks.

The goal of my code is to read the numbers 
    in a file line by line and for each line, 
    I store the numbers I got into a object of class Deque. 
    Therefore, I need an array of objects 
    of Deque to store all the numbers.
Similary to an array of linkedlist (Deque in my code).

The problem is I do not know how to initialized an array of this linkedlist (Deque in my code) properly so I can "push" all the keys in each linkedlist (Deque)

Comment: You've given a *lot* of code here, but not actually said what the problem is. It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advise and I have made it short and explained the problem I received

Comment: @pengzhong, a `NullPointerException` wont be thrown at the place you specified with the code you have. That's why you no one is answering. Also jonskeet asked for a _complete_ example too. If you breakup into many small chunks, it's difficult to debug. Create the shortest possible program with can reproduce the problem and post the whole program.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you applied Codebender's hint, you now just have to replace

```
s[i] = new Deque<Integer>();
```

with:

```
s[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

as you already mentioned in your question.

---

`java.util.Deque` is only an interface and therefore cannot be instantiated directly. All your variables (including the array) can still be of the type `Deque` and `Deque[]` respectively, since `java.util.LinkedList` implements that interface.

Comment: why Deque is a interface, I am confused.

Comment: I write Deque by myself in fact

Comment: Then you have to remove the 'import java.util.Deque;' line from the top of your class. Your given example code is using the java.util.Deque interface and not your own Deque class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I should not use the name "Deque" for my own class it is so confused.

Comment: Or don't write something that already exists, and spare your time reinventing the wheel (or in your case: stack).

Answer (score 1):

In your edited code, the problem is that you are just initializing the array. Not the `Deque` objects.

```
Deque<Integer>[] s = new Deque[10];
```

The above just creates an `Array` of 10 elements (and initializes all of them to `null`).

Hence `s[0]` is `null`, just like any other index. And you are trying to call `addFirst(1)` on `null` element.

So you should be initalizing each element in the array before using them,

```
s[i] = new Deque(); // In a loop if needed.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. the logic of "initializes all of them to null" is  fairly confused but I got it thanks.